# objects with same key values data

Tags: javascript, iteration

I have an object structured like this

```
{
"Mental Ability": [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "exams": [
        {
          "_e": "12",
          "years": [
            {
              "y": 2012,
              "freq": 3
            },
            {
              "y": 2011,
              "freq": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      "exams": [
        {
          "_e": "12",
          "years": [
            {
              "y": 2011,
              "ques_freq": 3
            },
            {
              "y": 2012,
              "freq": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want data like in Mental Ability inside exams years it should display like

```
'y': 2012
'freq': 4,
'y': 2011
'freq': 6
```

means the same years freq should be added and displayed 
like those exams years who are in y 2011 there frequency should be summed and displayed

Comment: Please provide JavaScript as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "ques_freq" is a typo for "freq", and o below is the object you mentioned.

```
function count(mentalAbility) {
  let out = {};
  mentalAbility.forEach(item => {
    item.exams.forEach(exam => {
      exam.years.forEach(year => {
        out[year.y] === undefined
          ? (out[year.y] = year.freq)
          : (out[year.y] += year.freq);
      });
    });
  });
  return out;
}

console.log(count(o['Mental Ability'])); // { '2011': 6, '2012': 4 }

function format(counts) {
  return Object.keys(counts).reduce((acc, year) => {
    acc.push({
      y: year,
      freq: counts[year]
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(format(count(o['Mental Ability']))); // [ { y: '2011', freq: 6 }, { y: '2012', freq: 4 } ]
```

Please note that I do not add any undefined / null checking for the field lookups